# Interface Design(WCF/Remoting)

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, remoting

I have two interfaces

```
public interface IServer1
{
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
void Subscribe();

[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ABC))]       
List<ABC> GetActiveData();
}
```

and another interface

```
public interface IServer2
{
void Subscribe(IClient client);

List<ABC> GetActiveData(IClient client);
}
```

One interface caters to WCF communication and the other to remoting.
It is irking me to create two interfaces for this. There will be two different proxies to implement these interfaces.

Can this be done with only one interface? or maybe it is best to have the two interfaces for this.
Also in the future there might be some other mode of inter process communcation that can come up apart from WCF and remoting, so would not like to create another interface for that as well.

As for removing remoting and using WCF only cant do that as its a huge code base. Would not want to have additional effort of testing etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I will follow the advice of encapsulate the concept that varies. In your case, the Service Interface seems to be consistent but communication mode may change.

Create one interface for the client and expose the interface via factory. Within Factory, depending upon the communication mode in use, create the proxy object and delegate the calls to the proxy object. This will encapsulate the Service Interface also i.e. Service Interface may be one or may be different, the client will not need to change unless the service interface offers same operations. Introducing new communication mode will require unit testing of Factory class only, the client code will not need to be unit tested.